# Calculating empirical distribution function from data

Tags: distribution, probability-density

Suppose that we have a matrix (n lines and 3 column) which represents the value of three variable X, Y, Z at some instants :

```
X    Y    Z

x1   y1   z1
x2   y2   z2
...
xn   yn   zn
```

Given that X is a discrete variable, Y and Z are continuous, how can we calculate the (empirical) distribution functions `f(x|y,z)`, `g(y|z)` and `h(x,y|z)`, `m(x)`?

Comment: Is the data continues or discrete?

Comment: the data is discrete